# I have unpacked the tuple, still getting error, can anyone explain what's wrong in this code?

Tags: python

[[image: I have unpacked the tuple, still getting error, can anyone explain what's wrong in this code?]] I have unpacked the tuple, still getting error, can anyone explain what's wrong in this code?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oyct.png)

Comment: Do not paste code as image, paste it as text. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The example outputs do not have the word "a", as in "a Engineer".  That seems awfully picky, but that's all I see.

Comment: Your code seems fine. In fact it works (i tried it). i think your output may not be matching the exact output of the problem (as these practice problems require the exact solution (in most of the cases)). So check that

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah you are right (i was searching for such thing but didn't found it )

Comment: Technically you could just get away with `.format(*person)`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. You've put `a` before the profession, and expected output doesn't have it

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code, I didn't get any errors but there was no output on the console.

I rewrote it this way

```
def guest_list(guests):

    for person in guests:
        name = person[0]
        age = person[1]
        profession = person[2]
        print("{} is {} years old and works as a {}".format(name, age, profession))


guest_list([("Ken", 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, "Lawyer"), ("Amanda", 25, "Engineer")])
```

Comment: There's not supposed to be runtime errors. They come from the test framework OP uses... Notice there's not an `a` before the profession.

Comment: i'm getting answers from both of our codes as expected. but while i submit my quiz i'm getting an error says REMEMBER TO UNPACK THE TUPLE INTO SEPARATE VARIABLES, THEN USE THOSE VARIABLES TO FORMAT THE OUT PUT. You can check the error down below the screenshot

Comment: Yeah added "a" before the profession, it works fine now, Thanks